# Cómo obtener un atributo de un botón que esta dentro de una tabla con Js o JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una tabla que en cada fila tiene botones uno de estos es eliminar y ahí en le pongo como atributo una ruta = "", al hacer `click` en el botón quiero que me muestre este valor pero me aparece

> undefined

```js
function eliminarMenu(cod) {
    var url = $(this).attr('ruta');
    console.log(url);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  id="eliiminarMenu" name="eliiminarMenu"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="ELIMINAR" onclick="eliminarMenu();" ruta="{{URL::to('menu/eliminar')}}/{{$menu->idMenu  }}" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

Cuando veo en el inspector del navegador el atributo ruta me sale correctamente lleno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para complementar del porque el codigo original no funciona:

Cuando agregas un atributo onclick en el contenido HTML automaticamente estas creando una funcion anonima que ejecuta el contenido de lo que agregas en el atributo. Dicha funcion anonima recibe `this` como el elemento actual, pero para las funciones invocadas `this` corresponde al objeto `Window`

En el codigo siguiente el boton `eliiminarMenu2` ejecuta `eliminarMenu.call(this)` efectivamente cambiando el contexto de ejecucion al esperado por la funcion.

Mientras que el boton `eliiminarMenu3` agrega un event handler de forma manual, apuntando a la funcion eliminarMenu directamente, sin intermediarios.

```js
function eliminarMenu(cod) {
    console.log("this es ", this.toString());
    var url = $(this).attr('ruta');
    console.log(url);
}

document.getElementById("eliiminarMenu3").onclick=eliminarMenu;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  id="eliiminarMenu" name="eliiminarMenu"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="ELIMINAR" onclick="eliminarMenu();" ruta="{{URL::to('menu/eliminar')}}/{{$menu->idMenu  }}" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Button</button>

<button  id="eliiminarMenu2" name="eliiminarMenu"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="ELIMINAR" onclick="eliminarMenu.call(this);" ruta="{{URL::to('menu/eliminar')}}/{{$menu->idMenu  }}" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Button con this</button>

<button  id="eliiminarMenu3" name="eliiminarMenu"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="ELIMINAR" ruta="{{URL::to('menu/eliminar')}}/{{$menu->idMenu  }}" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Button con event handler manual</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

ya que usas jquery, evita el uso onclick y agrega el evento `click` de jQuery

**html**

```
<button  id="eliiminarMenu" name="eliiminarMenu"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="ELIMINAR" ruta="{{URL::to('menu/eliminar')}}/{{$menu->idMenu  }}" class="btn btn-outline btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#eliiminarMenu').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('ruta');
    console.log(url);
});
```

Saludos